# Why does my browser import css rules from non-existent .less files when I include bootstrap.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

The only thing I included is

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

When I view the webpage in chrome development tool > styles, there are many css rules included from files

```
bootstrap/css/less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less
bootstrap/css/less/normalize.less
bootstrap/css/less/scaffolding.less
```

But there is no such files in my file system, and I am unable to find these filenames in `bootstrap.css`  .

Comment: Because of [sourcemaps](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Developer Tool is probabely reading the CSS Map by Bootstrap.

1) You can remove this map, `bootstrap.css.map` from your resources

2) You can disable it in the tool, `Settings -> Sources -> Enable CSS source maps`

[Here is an introduction guide to source maps](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps).